# Problems with timezones in xts time series

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have an issue that I'm running into on Windows. Suppose that I have the following data stored in a text file dat.csv:

```
timestamp, demand
2011-05-27 15:50:04, 38874
2016-03-27 01:30:03, 25107
```

This data is originally from a much larger csv file detailing the energy market in the UK. I attempt to create an xts time series object from this file as follows:

```
> library(xts)
> dat <- read.csv('dat.csv', sep=',', header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
> dat.xts <- xts(dat[, 2], 
>                order.by = strptime(dat$timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

However, when I attempt to view the resulting xts object, this is what happens:

```
> dat.xts
                     [,1]
2011-05-27 15:50:04 38874
<NA>                25107
```

As you can see, while the index for the first line was parsed correctly, that for the second line has resulted in an NA.

Interestingly, the same code appears to run correctly on Ubuntu 16.04. I suspect it's something to do with how timezones work on Windows but I'm not entirely certain about that. Can somebody explain how I can avoid this problem when running on Windows?

Comment: Check your second date for space, hidden characters etc ( `str(dat)`. I guess there is a typing/conversion error, because your code runs fine on Windows, macOS and Ubuntu.

Comment: Edit: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick. Turns out the data was dirtier than I thought.